# Is it possible to add more than one value against a Label for a Parameter in Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder and want to add more than one value against a Label (Available Values > Specify Values):

Example:

Label = "labelone"  Value = Value1, Value2...

When I run the report, I get a message saying Parameter1 is missing.

I have tried following against value:  Value1, Value2 and 'Value1', 'Value2'

My query has following in the where clause:  WHERE (FIELD in (@Parameter1))

Basically, I want to specify multiple values against one label under the parameter.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this directly as what will get passed to the query would be

```
WHERE Field IN ('Value1, Value2')
```

or

```
WHERE Field IN ('''Value1'', ''Value2''')
```

The way to do this would be split the label using a table valued function, you could use string_split if you have a fairly recent version of SQL Server (I think this was introduced in SQL2016). If you have an older version there are loads of sample of string splitting functions around tha you could use.

Once you have you function you can join to the results of that, the query would be something like

```
DECLARE @pValues TABLE (myValues varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @pValues
    SELECT * FROM string_split(@myReportParameter, ',')

SELECT * 
    FROM myTable a 
    JOIN @pValues p on a.Field = p.myValues
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was very helpful.  Working now!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Could you please mark the answer as accepted. That's the check mark to the left, under the vote up/down buttons. Thanks